# What is dynamic biased cache replacement policy?

Tags: cpu-cache

The [Arm documentation](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/100798/0401/L2-memory-system/About-the-L2-memory-system) for Cortex-A76 (Raspberry Pi 5) says the L2 cache replacement policy is "*dynamic biased*". But what is it?

More precisely:

1. How does it works?
2. Why not using pseudo-LRU, as for L1 cache?